# Why point is a circle with radius zero?

Tags: circles

I was reading this [What is a point circle, a real circle and an imaginary circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297793/what-is-a-point-circle-a-real-circle-and-an-imaginary-circle) and i get confused with the statement that is written in the accepted answer , i.e

**A point "circle" is just a point; it's a circle with a radius of zero**

But point itself is a circle and when we zoom it enough there is still a radius $>0$ , so how it is a circle of radius zero ???

Comment: "But point itself is a circle and when we zoom it enough there is still a radius >0, so how it is a circle of radius zero ???" - why do you think that?

Comment: You seem to be thinking of a point you draw with like a pencil. We're talking like a "mathematically ideal" point, which has no width, no length -- nothing going in any direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A point is defined to have no size. It is simply a location in space. I think the confusion arises because if you put a "point" of ink on a piece of paper and look closely enough, it seems to have a size.

But that dot of ink isn't really a point; it has a size. If you wanted a true mathematical point on paper, you will need a dot of ink that is so tiny, no other dot can be made that is smaller than it.

Comment: Even a single electron is not a point.

Answer (score 4):

To quote from Euclid's Elements, Book I, Definition 1

> A point is that which has no part.

In modern sense, part corresponds to dimensions. So, by the definition and tautology, when you zoom a point you shouldn't observe any dimensions.

In the question you have linked to, the OP asks about the meaning/intuition of some of the things, so when the radius is zero (that is when $g^2 +f^2 -c^2 =0$) we get a point, that is "something which has no dimensions", we call it a point circle in the context of analytic geometry just to make things a little intuitive, but in rigorous sense a point is not a circle of zero radius, it is not a square of zero length or any other thing like that.

Hope I was clear and it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

In various high school textbooks, when the radius of a circle is zero, it is said that it is a **degenerate circle of zero radius**. That means we're looking at a circumference of zero radius. Consequently, only one point belongs to the circumference, which is the centre.

Comment: Very nice explanation :).

Comment: @Knight Thank you very very much...

Answer (score 0):

There's a discrepancy between what can be drawn and what should exist in theory.
If you "zoom in" into the point you would see a circle. However, if you zoom in more, you would be able to delete the "outer" reaches of the circle and be left with a smaller circle which would still be considered a point.
Theoretically a point is a circle with no radius. However there is no way to draw it. It is not a concept you can visualize. Do you understand the logic though?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I agree with your statement "point itself is a circle",  This may be true according to this definition from the other post; "a circle is merely the set of points that are a fixed distance away from the center. If that fixed distance is zero, then that set of points is simply the center point itself.", or as I would put it, a point circle is a set containing  exactly one point.

However, this a mathematical and theoretical construct only. When you talk about "zooming in"  you seem to be implying that its a real physical thing that has dimensions.
In the physical world ( so far as we know) there is no such thing as a point circle, but in maths, there is.